# утилита при старте виртуальной машины 1с-bitrix на centos

Tags: битрикс, centos, vmware

Приветствую!
Учился cms bitrix с помощью сервера, который запускал в виртуальной машине, которую можно скачать с сайта 1с.
После ввода логина и пароля в виртуальной машине, попадал не сразу в консоль centos, а в интерфейс какой-то утилиты для настройки сети. Кто-нибудь может подсказать, что это за утилита, и можно ли ее установить на чистый centos?
[image: скриншот интерфейса утилиты]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, есть такая штука - «1С-Битрикс: Веб-окружение» - Linux

Вот ссылка, там требования и ссылка на уcтановщик https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/products/env/

Можно поставить на чистую ОСь спокойно, если данная ОС есть в списке рекомендуемых.

Если уж совсем для ленивых, вот что нужно вбить в консоли ОС (только посмотрите, подходит ли ваша ОС под нее):

```
wget http://repos.1c-bitrix.ru/yum/bitrix-env.sh 
chmod +x bitrix-env.sh 
./bitrix-env.sh
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за оперативность, но это я уже проделывал :)) скачивается, но запускаться не хочет с ошибкой... хотел заново проделать, чтоб точно указать ошибку.. но все заработало. Спаибо еще раз! :)

Comment: ну как бы, ответ верен, чтоб внукам осталось, отметь плиз как верный ответ:) а в след. раз пиши более содержательно проблему

Comment: слушай, верен, да не верен ;) установилось все окружение, этого мне не надо было, меня интересовала только утилита, в которой я оказывался после логина, в которой сразу вижу присвоенный ip и используемый адаптер

Comment: аа, ну вот опять из проблемы этого было не понятно ) если что, как бы я не настаиваю, не знал всей сути. Отдельно менюху ты никак не прикрутишь без полной установки, точнее ты прикрутишь, но работать это вряд ли будет стабильно и более-менее нормально

Comment: а для ip и адаптера, можешь написать свой bash скрипт, но это совсем другая история

Comment: Ладно, спасибо!